# ServiceStack Error When Installing from NuGet - Cryptogrphic Algorithm Not Supported

Tags: nuget, servicestack

When attempting to add ServiceStack via Nuget 1.8 to a Console Application I get the following message...

> The specified cryptographic algorithm is not supported on this
>   platform.

Unfortunately, I'm stuck using WinXP SP3.  Is ServiceStack now dependent on something a little more recent?

**UPDATE**
Apparently it was an issue with NuGet v1.8.  The problem has been resolved with NuGet v1.8.1 according to http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2240

Comment: When does this happen? Do you have a stacktrace or an example of the source code causing this error? What version of .NET do you have installed?

Comment: The issue is apparently fixed... http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2240
Just tossing up the idea of grabbing the source or building my own version with from the latest checkin.

Comment: I think I'll wait for v1.8.1 and use v1.7 for the moment

Comment: Yes, we will be releasing v1.8.1 next week to fix this regression.  Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for reporting it.

Answer (score 3):

We will investigate the issue. Meanwhile, you can download the 1.7 vsix from this link: http://nuget.codeplex.com/downloads/get/382255

Answer (score 0):

Update NuGet and the issue would be fixed